# Чи є термін кращий, ніж "перепост"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

В інтернет-спільноті існує явище публікації на своєму ресурсі (блозі, сторінці у соцмережі тощо) статей, які цілком взяті з іншого джерела.
Іншими словами, я читаю статтю, яка опублікована у ЗМІ чи в іншому блозі і роблю *«перепост»*, тобто, копіюю текст статті, вставляю посилання на першоджерело і публікую у себе (зі своїми коментарями чи без них).

Ця дія зазвичай називається *«перепост»*, дієслово *«перепощувати»* і дієприкметник *«перепощено»*. Я у своєму блозі використовую шапку такого виду:

> *Перепост допису: [Назва оригінального допису](http://#)*

Мені не дуже подобається це слово, тому що воно виглядає як калька з англійської ("*post*" = допис, публікація + префікс `пере-`).

З тієї само причини, мені також не подобається дієслово *«я перепощую»*.

Чи існує більш питоме українське слово, яким можна називати це явище? Я чув про наступні:

- дієсл. *реферувати*, дієприкм. *зреферовано* — також калька з англ.;
- *перепублікація* — занадто довге, як на мене;
- Cлово *"посилання"* означає іншу дію: (hyper-)link, reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Бачу що певна кількість сайтів у повідомленні щодо можливості використання матеріалів використовують слово "[передрук](http://sum.in.ua/s/peredruk)". Деякі сайти - електронні версії газет, але є і такі, що є просто веб-сайтами ніяк не пов'язаними з друкарською діяльністю (ба більше, займаються виключно веб-дизайном):

> Передрук матеріалів тільки за наявності посилання на [izvestiya.odessa.ua](http://izvestiya.odessa.ua)

або

> Будь-яке копiювання, публiкацiя, передрук чи наступне поширення iнформацiї та усіх інших матеріалів, в тому числі фото, дозволяється тільки за умови посилання на сайт [Волинської газети](http://volga.lutsk.ua/view/607/1/)

або

> Передрук матеріалів сайту заборонено. [webstudio2u.net](http://webstudio2u.net/ua/news/754-sinonimy-v-yandex-poiske-dlya-saitov.html)

або

> Передрук матеріалів можливий за умови публікації **активного гіперпосилання на сайт у першому абзаці.** *([povaha.org.ua](http://longread.povaha.org.ua/natalka-snyadanko-seksyzm-i-robota-tse-vzagali-zvuchyt-yak-synonimy/), виділення напівжирним моє)*

З власного досвіду, коли було очевидно що це нетиповий для мого блогу текст, писав просто "Оригінал: (посилання на оригінальну статтю)".

---

Як справедливо прокоментував Андрій Бандура, повідомлення "Волинської газети" дає приклади додаткових варіантів, похідних від "поширення", "копіювання" та "публікація":

- **Поширено допис** або **Поширення допису**, що запропоновано Андрієм Бандурою (додатково можна відзначити фонетичну подібність до англійського **Share**);
- **Копія допису** або **Копіювання допису**;
- Згадана вами **перепублікація**;
- Можливо просто **відтворення допису**.

Comment: Так, я також раніше використовував евфемізми як-то *«оригінал»*, але евфемізм не працює у випадку, коли потрібне дієслово: тоді доводиться використовувати інший евфемізм, як-то *«вкрав звідси»* тощо.

Comment: [Блог, -у](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191052&page=180).

Comment: Із вашого взірця випливає ще один варіант - слово „поширення“. Відповідний текст, буде звучати як „Поширено допис із“ або „Поширення допису“.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, ваш варіант може стати повноцінною відповіддю.

Comment: @Artemix, якщо АндрійБандура не робить свій коментар — відповіддю, то можливо, краще зробити CW-відповідь? Тоді буде логічно, що кожна відповідь пропонує свій один варіант.

Comment: @bytebuster Насправді така ідея в мене також була, я лінувався її дописати (якщо це когось цікавить звісно).

Comment: З *поширенням* є проблема: під цим ми, як правило, розуміємо розповсюдження лише посилання на матеріял автора (кнопка "share" у фейсбуці працює саме так), тоді як тут обговорюємо копіювання тексту.

Answer (score 8):

Якщо є *[до-пис](http://sum.in.ua/s/dopys)*, то за логікою щось має бути на основі *[писати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pysaty)*. Як щодо *[c-писувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/spysuvaty)*?

> **СПИСУВАТИ**
>
> 1. Писати, відтворюючи текст оригіналу; робити рукописну копію
>   ...
>   8. Точно відтворювати, копіювати що-небудь.

Приклади вживання:

> Списано звідси: <текст посилання>
>
> Списування дозволяється лише за письмового дозволу авторів.

Comment: Гм… неочікувано просте рішення, але подобається.

Comment: "Списано звідси..." - вдало, а як щодо "списав допис", "спиши допис"?

Answer (score 4):

[Перепис](http://sum.in.ua/s/perepys) може мати не тільки вже звичне значення, що означає [перелік](http://sum.in.ua/s/perelik) чи [облік](http://sum.in.ua/s/oblik) чогось [населення], а й дію «переписування» тощо.

> Дія за значенням [переписувати, переписати](http://sum.in.ua/s/perepysuvaty).

Приклад вживання:

> - Перепис з [посилання].
> - Перепис дозволяється лише за письмового дозволу авторів.
> - Перепис заборонений.

Списування дозволяється лише за письмового дозволу авторів.

Comment: Все ж, для справедливості — єдиний зазначений в СУМ-11 приклад для «[перепис](http://sum.in.ua/s/perepys) як дія за значенням переписувати, переписати» — це: «Він безпечно ходив з хати в хату — робив усьому своєму добру перепис (Панас Мирний).» — тобто саме в значенні «переоблік».

Comment: @Sasha встиг раніш за мене прокоментувати. Авторе, можливо, має сенс підшукати інші/додаткові посилання на приклади, які б підтверджували фактичне використання цього слова.

Comment: Є декілька прикладів [тут](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) (пошук за **лексемою** «перепис», розділ «художня проза»), наприклад, «перепис із вінілової платівки», «перепис [зміна] долі» тощо. Але це все твори після 2000. Іще [Грінченко](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/37786-perepys.html): «1) Копія рукописи».

Comment: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=i8NpAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81+%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81+%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 2):

З тих відповідей, які тут уже є, найбільш відповідною і природною видається пропозиція Андрія Бандури - "Поширення допису" або "Поширення". Це якщо вибирати з існуючих. Якщо потрібен свіжий синонім, можна додати "перепоширення". "Перепостити" справді неоковирне і в декого може викликати асоціацію зі "зловживанням пісною дієтою".